# How to map Unix Directories to Windows Server

Tags: windows, aix, file-transfer

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and an AIX 6.1 server. Now I would like to map 2 AIX folders to Windows for an application to access - The application on Windows is IBM Connect:Direct and needs to permanently transfer files to and from the Directories on the Unix server. On windows-to-windows this is easy, you just specify in the UNC paths in the Connect:Direct config files eg: `\\192.168.30.30\d$\BARC\Input\`

```
STEP1 COPY 
    FROM (
        FILE="&F"
    )
    TO (
        FILE="\\192.168.30.30\d$\BARC\Input\&DF"
        DISP=RPL
    )
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install Samba](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix_samba/). It provides Windows-compatible [SMB/CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) file and print sharing.

Comment: thank you Warren. So then you just connect to folders from the Windows system like you would to another windows system, eg: move c:\tests\*.dat \\192.168.100.100\Unix\tests ?

Comment: Thank you. I came across this post which also helps - https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012550